# Adding each created object to parent object

Tags: jquery

I have a function that takes user input and creates an object when a button is clicked.

My current output.

```
{
  item   : "1",
  inputs : [
    {
      input : "1",
      input : "2",
      input : "3"
    }
  [
}
```

What I am trying to do is for each time the button is clicked it creates the above object, while at the same time adding this object to another object.

```
{
  count   : 2,
  object  : [
    {
      item   : "1",
        inputs : [
          {
            input : "1",
            input : "2",
            input : "3"
          }
        [
      },
      {
        item   : "2",
        inputs : [
          {
            input : "1",
            input : "2",
            input : "3"
          }
        [
      }
    }
```

Does anyone have any way to accomplish this?

```js
$('#clickMe').on('click', function() {
  var MyObj = []
  var inputs = $('[name="input[]"]').map(
    function() {
      return $(this).val();
    }).get();

  var length = inputs.length;
  data = []

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var element = {
      "input": inputs[i]
    }
    data.push(element);
  }

  var item = {
    "item": $('#item').val(),
    "inputs": data
  }
  //console.log(item);
  MyObj.push(item);
  console.log(MyObj);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="item" value="">Item #
<br/>
<br/>
<input id="one" name="input[]" value="">
<input id="two" name="input[]" value="">
<input id="three" name="input[]" value="">
<br/>
<button id="clickMe">
Click Me
</button>
```

Comment: **1.** Indentation is your friend. The snippet tool has a *Tidy* button that can clean up your code for you. **2.** Your "examples" have a few issues, notably unclosed curly brackets and using `[` instead of `]`, though likely not important. **3.** If `myObj` (misnomer, by the way: This is not an object, it's an *array*) should persist through button clicks, then set it *outside* of the click handler. Currently, the very first line of your click event clears it completely.

Comment: Good to know for 1 & 2. Declaring the main array outside of my function creates the [object, object,] in the format that I was looking for. Thanks for the help.